# Windows ce Security Issue

Tags: visual-studio-2008, window

I have to run some projects (visual studio 2008) on windows ce 6.0 POS Device. But when I connect to the device, it says  "The device security configuration disallowed the connection. Ensure that you have the appropriate certificates on your device for development. Review your SDK documentation for proper security settings for connecting to this device". So I copied Visual Studio 2009 - VSDCert.cab file and tried to install it on the device. then it says "Its not a valid Windows ce Setup file". I don't know where i have done a mistake. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this today after I upgraded to Windows 10. I am using Visual Studio 2005 and got the same error message. But I was able to solve it. I would just like to share what I did:

1. Turn off the device.
2. Re-installed SP1 on my Visual Studio 2005
3. Run the Visual Studio 2005 as administrator
4. Run debug.

This way, I was able to resolve it.  Since you are using VS2008, maybe you can adjust to this solution to fit with the IDE you are using.